# VS 2017 unresolved external symbol __imp__stricmp (libcrypto_static.lib)

Tags: openssl, c++17, static-libraries, static-linking, libcrypto

I am statically linking OpenSSL libraries (on Windows) but I have around 30 linker errors, similar like this one:

`libcrypto_static.lib(o_names.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__stricmp`

As recommended, I used the directives:

`pragma comment(lib, "crypt32")
pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`

 also linker settings:

`Ignore Specific Default Libraries: libcmt.lib; msvcrt.lib;msvcrtd.lib`

If I remove the msvcrtd.lib from above, I can compile. But it is not correct as the msvcrtd.lib is used for dynamic linking and I wanted to link statically. The compiler should find missing definitions in libcmtd.lib (debug version). The compilation is using the /MT flag to use static linking.

What am I missing? it seems to me, that OpenSSL static crypto library still needs MS run-time dynamic DLL.

Comment: You need to use /MTd for the debug version and /MT for the release version. Do not explicitly ignore libcmt or libcmtd.

Comment: Yes, I am using MT or MTd as needed. Ignoring libcmt.lib is recommended by MS. The result should be that the debug version of library will be used: libcmtd.lib

Comment: It looks like you need to rebuild libcrypto and libssl with these flags. libcrypto_static.lib is a static library itself but it links with the dynamic MS runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486243/how-do-i-build-openssl-statically-linked-against-windows-runtime

Comment: Yes, as mentoned in the last comment in your link, the OpenSSL is using MT nowadays. I am thinking, as they remove all default libraries during OpenSSL build, I should add some. Which one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The __imp decoration means the library is built with /MD.

Comment: This solution [compiling the openssl binary statically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63607013/7535705)